# AliasMatch in httpd.conf with django admin

Tags: regex, django, apache, django-wsgi

I have a problem with Alias in apache with django. In my wsgi.conf I have the following alias:

```
Alias /admin/static/ /opt/python/current/app/django_eb/static/
<Directory /opt/python/current/app/django_eb/static>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The alias works fine but in my django admin I get the static only in some pages. The problem is related with the alias path because the django admin includes additional parts to the url according to the section. An example following:

```
http://blablabla.com/admin/**auth/group**/static/admin/css/base.css/
```

For each django app, additional information is added to the url and the Alias fails to resolve. Are there any way to map this situation using AliasMatch instead Alias?

I suppose that I can map manually every additional path using a simple alias but that is not an efficient and comfortable solution...

Thanks!!

Comment: You should not have to go through all that mapping. Is your `STATIC_URL` set to a root directory like `/static/`? If so, you should only need `Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/django_eb/static/` and don't forget to run `collectstatic`.

Comment: Hi!! you are right my problem was related with the STATIC_URL I had set it to static/. I have changed it to /static/ and now it works smooth :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have to go through all that mapping. Is your `STATIC_URL` set to a root directory like `/static/`? If so, you should only need `Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/django_eb/static/` and don't forget to run `collectstatic`.
                    – Nostalg.io

you are right my problem was related with the STATIC_URL I had set it to static/. I have changed it to /static/ and now it works smooth – rdiaz82